# Is it possible to post on facebook wall an edited google map?

Tags: asp.net, facebook, google-maps-api-3, asp.net-mvc-5

My ASP.Net MVC5 application allows users to create their own trip database using google maps api. Now I would like to allow them to post on their facebook walls those trips. Do you have any ideas on how I can achieve this? I don't need a final answer, I would be more than satisfied with some insight about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you could use OpenGraph Custom Stories to achieve that. Have a look at the guide at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/getting-started to get an overview.

Baseline is that you could post via OpenGraph Actions/Stories something like "User XYZ created  a Trip with MapMyTrips" to the authenticated User's activities, and when Users click on it they get referred to your site and the individual Trip.