# Sharing Geolocation via link?

Tags: facebook, hyperlink, geolocation, maps, share

I am currently working on a small site, where you are supposed to be able to share your location via facebook.
I have created a site with google maps, which tracks the users location.
I then added a Facebook-share button in the bottom.
What I would like to do now, is to be able to share that location via facebook.
So if you share your location, and I opens the link in Facebook, I get your shared position in google maps.
You can see the current website here: http://mads064d.keaweb.dk/m3/geo.html

Does it makes sense?

Hope so!
Thank you!

Comment: I get a 403 Forbidden error when clicking your link.

Comment: It appears the server only allows tracking from Denmark.
Weird. I have uploaded the HTML document on this link.
So sorry.
http://www.mediafire.com/view/g2almbb2l7mgx5p/geo.html

Answer (score 0):

Your site is not reachable -> 403.

What you could do is using the OpenGraph obect type `place` as described here:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/object-type/place/

Probably you'll need to create the object (save the `object_id`) on the fly before sharing it, and update it each time neccessary.

Also, see

- [Is it possible to post on facebook wall an edited google map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22069160/is-it-possible-to-post-on-facebook-wall-an-edited-google-map/22069826#22069826)

Comment: Okay!
I am looking at that right now.
Still having a hard time figuring it out.
So sorry for the website is down.
It appears, it only allows traffic from Denmark.
I have uploaded the HTML here:
http://www.mediafire.com/view/g2almbb2l7mgx5p/geo.html